# Linking a Xamarin Forms app to an API

Tags: c#, jquery, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have an idea for a project in college. 
The idea is to make a Xamarin app that will find the cheapest flight between an entered date from a select number of airlines for the user. (Just like SkyScanner or Expedia)

I think the best way to do this would be by extracting the data from the airline's API's and comparing the flights that way.

What I was wondering is what would be the best way to do this? I'm proficient in C# and Javascript/Jquery. Any help is welcome.

Comment: "I have a vague idea for an app, please design the architecture for me" questions are generally considered Off Topic for a number of reasons

Comment: The first step is to figure out what endpoint you are going to be pulling from. Once you can get a sample JSON request defined in the browser/POSTMAN/etc, you can use something like https://quicktype.io/ or https://jsonutils.com/ to define your types. Your next step would be tutorials on `HttpClient` or simply googling "How to query a REST service in C#"

Comment: @JonDouglas can you suggest any good tutorials?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on C#, then you can do all the work on it.

1) You will need to build a Web API project and build and endpoit to work with. You have an example of this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Based on what you want to do, you will have to handle the GET request. Then you can send the parameters as query parameters on your URI. Example: http://localhost/api/values/?datetime=1505766470

2) You will need to send the actual request from your mobile application. For doing this, you can do something like this:

```
  RestUrl = http://developer.xamarin.com:8081/api/todoitems/
  var uri = new Uri (RestUrl);
  ...
  var response = await client.GetAsync (uri);
  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
      var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
      Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<TodoItem>> (content);
  }
```

You have the whole example right here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/rest/